# calling each on a string object

Tags: ruby

This code (by someone else) might have been written using an older version of Ruby because now I'm getting an error calling 'each' on a string object. The maze string below gets passed to the `maze_string_to_array` method. When it's run, it yields this error in `maze_string_to_array'

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000100854ac0>
```

Can you explain what the problem is, and how to fix it?

```
   def maze_string_to_array(mazestring)
        @maze = []
        mazestring.each do |line|        
            @maze.push line.chomp
        end
    end
```

Maze string

```
MAZE1 = %{#####################################
# #   #     #A        #     #       #
# # # # # # ####### # ### # ####### #
# # #   # #         #     # #       #
# ##### # ################# # #######
#     # #       #   #     # #   #   #
##### ##### ### ### # ### # # # # # #
#   #     #   # #   #  B# # # #   # #
# # ##### ##### # # ### # # ####### #
# #     # #   # # #   # # # #       #
# ### ### # # # # ##### # # # ##### #
#   #       #   #       #     #     #
#####################################}
```

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Guess you could replace the whole method with `mazestring.split(/\n/)` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.8 String#each used to iterate through lines.  In 1.9, String#each_line does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This code is unnecessarily verbose. The whole method can be written with a `map` and using 1.9 [String#lines](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-lines) instead of the old 1.8.x [String#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-each) to split lines:

```
@maze = mazestring.lines.map(&:chomp)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9 use `each_line` instead of `each`.

But it looks as if you could replace the whole method with `mazestring.split(/\n/)` anyway.